# ¿Como validar una fecha entre dos columnas en un tabla de la db? en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Estoy probando de esta manera:

```
Turnos::whereBetween(DB::raw("'".$req->crear_hora_inicial2."'"), ['hora_inicio','hora_final'])
      ->orWhereBetween(DB::raw("'".$req->crear_hora_final2."'"), ['hora_inicio', 'hora_final'])
      ->exists()
```

Esto me crea el siguiente sql:

```
select 
    exists(
        select 
            * 
        from 
            "turnos" 
        where 
            '03:00' between 'hora_inicio' and 'hora_final' 
            or
            '06:59' between 'hora_inicio' and 'hora_final'
    ) 
as "exists"
```

El problema es que las columnas que son `hora_inicio` y `hora_final` deberian `tener doble comilla (")`, con `comilla simple` la base de dato lo interpreta como un `string` y yo requiero que me lo reconozca como una columna, como ya dije comillas dobles.

**Actualización 1:**

No encontraba solución he hice esto provisionalmente:

```
DB::select( DB::raw("select exists(select * from turnos where '$inicio' between hora_inicio and hora_final or '$fin' between hora_inicio and hora_final) as exists") );
```

El resultado (por Debugbar) es el siguiente:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#641
    +"exists": false
  }
]
```

¿Como podría obtener solo el boolean de `exists`?

Answer (score 1):

Considero que no hay forma de hacer esto con `whereBetween`, es un método creado solo para manejar valores y no nombres de columnas.

```
/**
 * Add a where between statement to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  array   $values
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @param  bool  $not
 * @return $this
 */
public function whereBetween($column, array $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
{
    $type = 'between';

    $this->wheres[] = compact('column', 'type', 'boolean', 'not');

    $this->addBinding($values, 'where');

    return $this;
}
```

La única forma que se me ocurre sin utilizar consultas "raw" sería agrupando consultas:

```
$hora1 = $req->crear_hora_inicial2;
$hora2 = $req->crear_hora_final2;

where(function ($query) use ($hora1) {
    $query->where('hora_inicio', '<=', $hora1);
    $query->where('hora_final', '>=', $hora1);
})
orWhere(function ($query) use ($hora2) {
    $query->where('hora_inicio', '<=', $hora2);
    $query->where('hora_final', '>=', $hora2);
})
```

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta y coloque como lo resolví, provisionalmente, no creo que sea lo adecuado pero me da solución y adjunto coloque otra pregunta. De antemano gracias por tu ayuda :D